# Ridiculously long HTTP response time in browers for moderately-sized response body

Tags: docker, http, flask, browser, gunicorn

One page in my Flask web application returns a list of entries based on some filter supplied by the user. When there are too many items (more specifically, when the size of the HTML page excess 150KB), the browser will take forever (over 2 minutes) to load the page. During the wait, a partial list is displayed in the browser, which confuses some users. On the other hand, smaller pages (<= 100KB) will load almost instantly. See [this link](https://share.firefox.dev/3vQCZCz) for a Firefox Profiler recording made on Firefox Developer Edition.

I first suspected a web/application server misconfiguration, but the issue cannot be reproduced with the `curl` command copy & pasted from Firefox's development tool (I can see the HTML response right away). Then perhaps it's due to my browser's specificities? Well no, besides Firefox, such long pages also take forever to load on Firefox Developer Edition, Chrome, and Microsoft Edge.

Additionally information:

- The application is deployed with Docker and [`meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker`](https://github.com/tiangolo/meinheld-gunicorn-flask-docker).
- The problem does not manifest itself when I launched the application with Flask's debug server outside of Docker.
- The network latency should be extremely low since I'm sitting on the same floor as the server.
- I have root access to the server, which is `Linux mwfsh 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 16:34:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

How should I address the ridiculously long HTTP response time? Which commands should I run to get a better idea of the underlying issue?

Comment: wild guess: the announced content-length is incorrect, and the browsers wait and then time out.